# ActiveStorage::UnpreviewableError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, rubygems, preview, poppler

I'm trying to create a PDF preview for my PDF files, but I don't know where to start, I'm using poppler gem on Ruby on Rails.

The app is giving me this message: "ActiveStorage::UnpreviewableError in Tasks#show"

So I'm not understanding where should I need to declare the preview

Looking on google I found several sites with methods, but I don't know where to add this code, I've tried by creating a new folder on the app directory, but this didn't work.

Comment: can we see the code that isn't working? and you can start here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#displaying-images-videos-and-pdfs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[In activestorage documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#requirements) says about requirements to use this feature.

- libvips v8.6+ or ImageMagick for image analysis and transformations
- ffmpeg v3.4+ for video previews and ffprobe for video/audio analysis
- poppler or muPDF for PDF previews

Check if in your environment has the requirements

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice, I realized I haven't installed muPDF on my environment, the thing that worked for me was to install it from the home directory (outside my project) and that's it, now the preview is working perfectly fine.

https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/05/install-mupdf-1-3-0-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).